# Maven, archetype:generate, is there any GUI tool for this?

Tags: maven

When I launch **mvn archetype:generate**, it is really tiresome to search through that huge list of numbers and names in order to generate a skeleton project.
Is there any GUI tool for this?
I would really like a GUI tool where the "archetype:generate" project types are nicely grouped and sorted.

Comment: mostly are IDEs: IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, etc. There's no gui of any sort, that I ever heard of.

Answer (score 1):

[eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) offers a "New Maven Project" wizard with Archetype selection.

[image]

I suppose other IDEs with Maven integration will provide similar functionalities.